# GeoNetwork : link a PostGIS table to a metadata (add an online resource)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geonetwork, url, jdbc

With GeoNetwork, I have to link a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table to my GeoNetwork metadata via "add an online ressource", what is the rule to write the URL in order to connect to the PostgreSQL server ? For information, I have to set a specific schema. I tried the following URL but it does not work :

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DATABASE_NAME?id:pswd@currentSchema=SCHEMA_NAME
```